# Silverlight Listbox with multiple selection mode

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Silverlight windows phone 7.
Listbox with selectionmode multiple.

How to make certain items selected by default.
listbx.SelectedItems seems to have only get method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `SelectionMode` as `Extended`
**XAML:**

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" SelectionMode="Extended">
    <ListBoxItem>First</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Second</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Third</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Fourth</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

**C#:**

```
        this.listBox.SelectedItems.Add(this.listBox.Items[1]);
        this.listBox.SelectedItems.Add(this.listBox.Items[2]);
```

HTH

Comment: Any other ways setting SelectedItems from viewmodel?