# How can I delete items from MultiselectList?

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I am using `MultiselectList` from the Silverlight Toolkit. When I checked items from `MultiselectList`, how can I delete these items?

This is a sample in C#:

```
for (int i = checkedListBox1.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
{ 
    if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i)) 
    { 
        checkedListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i); 
    } 
}
```

I need a code sample for Windows Phone 7.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with

```
    while (multiselectList1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        multiselectList1.Items.Remove(multiselectList1.SelectedItems[0]);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code

```
    foreach(ListBoxItem item in listBox.SelectedItems)
    {
       listBox.Items.RemoveAt(listBox.SelectedIndex);
    }
```

Comment: Is there a MultiselectList in wp7 if yes give me the answer link? According to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811343/silverlight-listbox-with-multiple-selection-mode     my answer is correct.

Comment: There is a MultiselectList in the Silverlight Toolkit: https://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/71550

Comment: Yes, sorry i had given answer for wp7